# nodejs returns jumbled variable content when concurrent

Tags: node.js, web3js

**DEMO1**

```
bot.on(async (msg) => {
    result = await contract.methods.name().call()
    console.log(result)

})

bot.start()
```

**DEMO2**

```
bot.on(async (msg) => {
    async function demo() {
        result = await contract.methods.name().call()
        return result
    }

    result = demo()
    console.log(result)
})

bot.start()
```

demo1 can return correct results when concurrent, demo2 can return confusing variable content when concurrent, what causes this

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
result = await demo();
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for your code, I tried await demo(), this will convert program logic to serial, can't handle concurrency

Comment: why you want to create a function to do this the Demo1 is better way

Comment: bot.on gets the message from telegram, demo func is responsible for processing the message and passing it to telegrambot, Because the logic of processing messages is more complex, multiple functions are required to process

Comment: I can write all the message processing code inside the arrow function, which can return the correct result when concurrent, but if I write the message processing code into the func to return, the result will be messed up

Comment: I found the solution, create a tesk function to manage all func calls